# How to Access/Write File in Hippo Webfile(Bootstrap) from controller?

Tags: java, hippocms

I am trying to write a JSON file from my Controller to Bootstrap webfiles.
I have created a folder in webfiles named **json** and I tried to write into a file on this path (/webfiles/site/json/< filename >). I am using Using Java IO Filewriter to write the file but i am getting the following exception :

```
Exception in file writing : webfile:\json\v2_json_v2c2JSON.json (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Is there a way to find out the root of the project ?

Comment: Could you explain what is the Controller in your context? Are you trying to create an implementation for the development environment or for a deployed and running instance?

Comment: I achieved it by using servlet context. But, I am sure if this is the right way to do it in HIPPO. See below :

String contextPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
  String path = contextPath + "../../../../bootstrap/webfiles/src/main/resources/site/json/c2_json_v2/";